# Autofill field in a laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel app, a simple eloquent call generates a new id for the new item in my table. `$Article = new Article;`

If I wanted to also generate a custom code at the same time, how would I do that?

I tried this:

```
protected $fillable = [
'RandomReference' => substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7),
...
```

but get this error:  `Constant expression contains invalid operations`

Doesn't help if I make it a protected field (rather than fillable) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a **Mutator** and I believe it to be the most Laravelish approach.

Add the following to your Eloquent model:

```
public function setRandomReferenceAttribute()
{
    $this->attributes['RandomReference'] = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
}
```

Please, look for further details in the official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correctly, the mutator will "interrupt" the call to set the value of an attribute, and allow me to modify it. But since the attribute I wnat to create is totally independant, it makes more sense to use the boot method proposed by alariva. I'm probably being a bit purist.

Comment: `boot()` in the model is deprecated, you would use `Observers` instead. But a mutator exists to tackle exactly your scenario. It is silently triggered when creating a new entry and ignored when updating the entry.

Comment: Ah, well that's it then. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 12):

The `fillable` attribute expects a list of attribute names. You won't be able to pass any dynamic call to generate data for those attributes.

You may use the `boot` method to autogenerate the attribute upon creation event.

```
protected $fillable = [
  'RandomReference', /* ... */
];

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($model) {

        $model->RandomReference = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);

    });
}
```

See [this reference](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-help-generating-attribute-values-before-creating-record) for more examples.